# What will be best solution for language translation in angular 2?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I already have a json file with translation of each word to its equivalent in 5 languages. These words are the ones that have been used throughout the site and I won't be needing anyother library or plugin to handle translations. What will be best way to implement this in angular 2.

The solution that I came up with:
 1. to set a cookie with the language chosen.
 2. Use pipes to translate the words and sentences by accessing the cookie value from the pipe.

Is this a good idea to do this?

Comment: are there any problem using a good library which uses JSON files?

Comment: I didn't find any library that was using my own dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the JSON files (note that they should contain translations of whole sentences or phrases, rather than single words) then you should go ahead with [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate).

You can also go with a build-in [Angular2 Internationalization framework](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html), but it will force you to use XLIFF or XMB file format - it uses bit different than traditional principles, in exchange for scalability and flexibility.